# Not able to mock data coming from Mapper class using mockito

Tags: java, mocking

I have written unit test with Mockito to test controller, where I get back data from database using mapper.but due to for example : `@Param("abc") abc` parameters in mapper I am not able to retrive mocked data.

public class classUnderTest {

```
    @Mock
    private ProductMapper productMapper;

    List<ProductKey> productKeys;

    String firstName;

    String lastName;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        productMapper = Mockito.mock(ProductMapper.class);
        productKeys = new ArrayList<ProductKey>();
        firstName = "John";
        lastName = "Rebbeca";

    }

    @Test
    public void getInsureddetails() {
        Mockito
                .doReturn(productKeys)
                .when(ProductMapper)
                .getProductKeyByInsured(firstName, lastName);
    }
}


public interface ProductMapper{
    public List<ProductKey> getProductKeyByInsured(@Param("firstName")String firstName, @Param("lastName")String lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hard code parameters, then it will work only when the parameters match the hardcoded values while invoking. Either invoke the method with the values that you hardcoded or generalize it as follows.

`Mockito.when(orderMapper.getOrderKeyByInsured(Matchers.anyString(),Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(orderKeys);`